# Powershell ISE not detecting specific parameter value

Tags: powershell

I have developed a powershell script in which I have created function which takes 3 input parameters.

Wierd part is if I pass 5029D as second parameter, the color of it does not change to light purple which is color of other parameters.

[image: Wierd_Part]

But if I give anything else, for ex 5029A its color is changing to light purple as expected.

[image: OK_Part]

Because of above issue logic of my fuction is not working as expected for 5029D alone. For other parameter it is working fine.

What all things I have tried till now:

1. Ran Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue and restarted IMS Session.
2. Restarted IMS session multiple times

Env Details:

Powershell Version: 5.1.14409.1018
Windows Version: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition

Please help as I am stuck and I am completely clueless.

Comment: did you try adding quotes around them? `dbsi -dbhost "servername" -dbprefix "5029A" -custname "abcd"

Comment: `d` is a numeric literal. It has a special functionality when used with a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `d` or `D` is suffixed to a decimal number, it is parsed as a [numeric literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7). If your intention is to pass a value as a string, then simply quote it or hard type your `dbprefix` parameter:

**Option 1 - Using Quotes:**

```
dbsi -dbhost servername -dbprefix "5029D" -custname abcd
```

**Option 2 - Setting Parameter Type:**

```
function dbsi {
    param($dbhost,[string]$dbprefix,$custname)
    $dbprefix
}
dbsi -dbhost servername -dbprefix 5029D -custname abcd
```

---

Essentially, `5029D` is converted to `5029` as a decimal data type when the `D` is applied. Without the `d`, `5029` would by default be typed as an integer. See below:

```
(5029).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType

(5029D).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Decimal                                  System.ValueType
```